# Switching connection strings depending on Environment in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have created a development and a production environment as well as two appsettings[environment].json files. Both appsettings have different connection strings for a dev and live database. I am able to switch between environments easily enough but in doing so I was hoping that the environment would be pointing at the database relevant to my environment.

When creating the database using Entity Framework Core and any migrations, I am looking for a way to switch between connection strings depending on my envinronment. Below are my appsettings.json and launchSettings.json files. I am currently using ASP.NET Core 3.1...

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DevDb": "dev connection string here"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Db": "Live Conn string here"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Launch Settings

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50301",
      "sslPort": 44314
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "DOLS (UAT)": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      }
    },
    "DOLS (LIV)": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      },
      "applicationUrl": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Startup class

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Db")));
           

            }
```

Program Files

```
  public class Program
        {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use `Manage User Secrets` instead of two `appsettings.json` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows#json-structure-flattening-in-visual-studio

Comment: Use the same name for the connection string in an environment-specific file. By default, you can use `appsettings.Production.json`. What you ask is how configuration and `appsettings....json` already work. You don't need anything else. No secrets, no factories. In .NET Core Configuration multiple providers can provide the same setting and the last one wins. `appsettins.production.json` is loaded *after* `appsettings.json`, s the `

Comment: @Arsen using secrets solves a completely different problem. What if both connection strings use Windows Authentication but point to different servers and databases?

Answer (score 2):

For dynamic `ConnectionString` you can use your own `DbContextFactory` to create the Database with new `ConnectionString` in runtime and this way you don't need 2 different `appsettings.json`,

#The DbContextFactory

```
public static MyDbContext Create(string conString, IConfiguration configuration)
{  
    try
    { 
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(conString);
        return new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // ignored
        Log.Error(ex?.ToString());
    }  
}
```

the above code will create new Instance of `MyDbContext` in runtime from the given `ConnectionString`

#Uses

```
myDbContext = DbContextFactory.Create(conStr, Configuration);// you pass the ConnectionString based on the Envirionment
```

If you want `MyDbContext` to be available for all the Controller by default then you can simply create a base Controller and initialize the `MyDbContext` there so it will be available to all other Controller that inherit from the base Controller.

#`OnActionExecuting` base Controller

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)  
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(context);

    if(env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        conStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection");
    } 
    else
    {
        conStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("LiveConnection");
    }

    myDbContext = DbContextFactory.Create(conStr, Configuration); 
}
```

This is the simplest way to create any `DbConnection` anytime you want in runtime if the `ConnectionString` is valid.

Comment: There's no need for this. ASP.NET Core allows overriding settings already. That's why `appsettings.Production.json` is used to override the settings in `appsettings.json`

Comment: Hey panagiotis-kanavos, thank you for your response. Building on my question then, is it possible to point to a particular appettings[environment].json when in package manager console. Lets say I wanted to create a database but only on the dev box?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think for this you will need to set the Environment variable in the server to use different `appsettings.[env].json`

Comment: Which is the whole point. With your code you still need to detect the environment, but now the options are hard-coded, in a class that has nothing to do with settings - the controller. The DbContextFactory itself plays no role at all

Comment: Understand your point, My goal was to change the `ConnectionString` on runtime.

Comment: very unnecessary. this is normally done via config system. to get a dynamic connection string during runtime EF provides the OnConfiguring method that can be overridden in the DbContext. this is how multitenant SaaS apps fetch connection string based on the tenant that is making an API call, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to change anything as long as you have the same name for the `ConnectionString` in both configuration files.

The correct connection string will be set on `ConfigureServices` based on the environment.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer operating system environment variables for this kind of problem. then in the dev server, I put the dev database connection string and in the production, I put the prd database connection string. and not just the connection string i put all the non-constant values the base URL of any third-party service. because they can have a sandbox env for your dev env and live env for your prd env. you can simply extract the value with this:

```
using System;
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Db")));
```

you can add a new environment variable like this. [click here](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/)
after that you need to restart your IDE in local. or on server whatever you're using for hosting for iis server you need to run this command on cmd **iisreset/restart**.